# Convert text to number in Libre Calc

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice, calc

I have a spread sheet containing percentages which have a "'" prefix, e.g. "'18.93%". I can't therefore treat them as numbers.

Find and replace cannot find a single instance of "'", so I cannot convert them en masse. How can I automate this conversion?

Older answers to this topic no longer seem to work.

---

Implementing suggestion:

Am I doing something wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibreOffice ignores the initial single quote for all purposes other than forcing the cell value to be treated as text.  That said, in LibreOffice 7.5.9 I was able to do a **Find and Replace** with:

- **Regular expressions**: on
- **Find**: `(\d+[.]\d+[%])`  (in parentheses to create a capturing group)
- **Replace**: `$1`  (also `=$1` works)

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestion but it's still struggling. Could you glance over the screenshot I added and see if I'm making a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: You have not activated the option **Regular expressions**.

Comment: (On the other hand, you have activated **Current selection only**, which limits the find to the cells currently selected in the sheet: be sure that is what you want, otherwise uncheck it.)

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for overlooking that.

Comment: You are welcome, glad that helped.